# How to use HTTP in hyperstack

Tags: hyperstack

I have made a basic install of a hyperstack rails app using hyperstack.org's installation instructions, trying to add a `HTTP.get` request in an `after_mount` callback.

Not really sure what else I could try, thought HTTP would be a standard option

```
class App < HyperComponent
  include Hyperstack::Router

  after_mount do
    HTTP.get('/example.json')
  end

  render do
    DIV() do
      'App'
      # NodeDisplay
      # define routes using the Route psuedo component.  Examples:
      # Route('/foo', mounts: Foo)                : match the path beginning with /foo and mount component Foo here
      # Route('/foo') { Foo(...) }                : display the contents of the block
      # Route('/', exact: true, mounts: Home)     : match the exact path / and mount the Home component
      # Route('/user/:id/name', mounts: UserName) : path segments beginning with a colon will be captured in the match param
      # see the hyper-router gem documentation for more details
    end
  end
end
```

the error received is:

```
Uncaught error: HTTP: uninitialized constant App::HTTP
in App (created by Hyperstack::Internal::Component::TopLevelRailsComponent)
in Hyperstack::Internal::Component::TopLevelRailsComponent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: The HTTP library is not by default included in Opal or Hyperstack.

You can include it as part of the Opal jQuery wrapper, or with a minimal Opal `Browser::HTTP` library.

**To add the jQuery wrapper to your Hyperstack application do the following:**

> 1. Import the Hypestack jquery wrapper by adding
>      `import 'hyperstack/component/jquery', client_only: true`
>      to your `config/initializers/hyperstack.rb` file.
> 2. Then include the actual jquery javascript code in your assets:
>      If using webpacker run `yarn add jquery` in your terminal, and then add this line to the `javascripts/packs/client_only.js` file:
>      `jQuery = require('jquery');`
>      If **not** using webpacker instead add `import 'jquery', client_only: true` to the hyperstack initializer file.

**If you just want to use the more minimal `Browser::HTTP` module, add**

> `import 'browser/http`
>
> to your `config/initializers/hyperstack.rb` file.
>
> After changing your hyperstack.rb you will have to clear the rails tmp cache by running `rm -rf tmp/cache`
>
> *Note: When using the browser version you will need to use `Browser::HTTP` instead of simply `HTTP`.*